# Django defining for user - item completion in app

Tags: python, django, django-models

it would be great if I could have your opinion, apologies I am fairly new to Django and struggling on how to model this relationship. Basically I have a series of courses

```
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track,verbose_name="Learning track", default=1, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 240, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 100, null=True, blank=True, unique= True)
```

and in a course we have lectures:

```
class Lecture(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course,verbose_name="Lecture Course", default=1,blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 240, null=True, blank=True)
    tags = GenericRelation("TaggedItem", null=True, blank=True)
```

My question is what is the best way to model each of the items completion by a particular user, allowing to express things such as:
"user A has completed 50% of lecture 1" 
*and* "user A has completed 80% of course ABC"

What I had in mind is using contenttypes for this but not sure it is the best approach from a data modelling perspective - any advice or ideas you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: you could create a separate model with the completion %, and foreign keys to the user and the course/lecture

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate class like so:

```
class LectureCompletion(models.Model):
    lecture = models.ForeignKey(Lecture)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student) #assuming your student model is called student
    completion_percentage = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

For the course you could do the same thing,or you can calculate the completion percentage of the course from the students completion of the lectures comprised in the course.

e.g.:

if you create a instantiate LectureCompletion for each of the lectures of a course when a student enrolls in a course you could do the following, if you calculate the completion percentage as the avg percentage of completion in each lecture:

if you have student and course instantiated:

```
lectures_completion = LectureCompletion.objects.filter(student = student)
course_pct = 0
count = 0
for lecture_completion in lectures_completion:
    if lecture_completion.lecture.course = course # assuming you have course instantiated
        course_pct = course_pct + lecture_completion.completion_percentage
        count = count + 1
course_pct = course_pct / count
```